# Find conditional distribution without using the definition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$ be i.i.d with
$Z_{1}\sim N(0,1)$ and 
$Z_{2}\sim N(0,1)$

Let $X_{1}=m_{1}Z_{1}$ and
let $X_{2}=m_{2}Z_{1}+m_{3}Z_{2}$

where $m_{1},m_{2},m_{3}$ are constants.

Find the conditional distribution of $f(X_{2}|(X_{1}=a))$ without using the definition of the conditional pdf. (Note $a$ is a constant)

My question is that when I write $a=m_{1}Z_{1}$ and I re-arrange to get $(a/m_{1})=Z_{1}$, then the left hand side is a constant wheras the right hand side is a random variable. Is this not a contradiction? Also, $E(Z_{1})=E(a/m_{1})=a/m_{1}$. But we know $Z_{1}$ is a standard normal, so it's expectation is $0$.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Given that (i.e. conditional on) $X_1=a$, you do indeed have $Z_1$ being a constant namely $\dfrac{a_{\, }}{m_1}$, presuming that $m_1\not = 0$.  So the conditional expectation is $E[Z_1\mid X_1=a]=\dfrac{a_{\, }}{m_1}$ while the unconditional expectation is $E[Z_1]=0$

Comment: You are not putting a constraint on $Z_1$, you are just selecting the points in the domain for which the constraint is true. When I ask what the average die roll value is given that the value is even, I am not constraining the die, I am just ignoring the odd values.